# Recognize the body width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, resolution

I need a little script which allows me to do this:

```
if(// window body Height is less then 660px) {
       // code to be executed if condition is true 
} 
else { 
      // code to be executed if condition is false 
}
```

Hope there is a simple solution for that!

**EDIT:**

I have this now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
                       
if(parseInt($('body').height())<660){
    $("#container").addClass("small");
}
else{
    $("#container").removeClass("small");
}
 });
```

But it's not working, anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the viewport height (the height of the area in which the web-page is displayed in) or the document height (the height of the web-page)?

Comment: Although you probably didn't realize it, that's an important piece of information.

Comment: @Jonathan In that case I recommend `$( 'html' ).height()`. The non-jQuery way to get this value would be `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`.

Comment: Also consider running this code "onresize" (whenever the user re-sizes the browser window).

Comment: @Šime Vidas Exactly also onresize! but how..? And sorry its the viewport, not the document height.. btw check my EDIT

Comment: FYI, it's "thanks in advance". No trailing "d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( window ).resize(function () {
    $( container ).toggleClass( 'small', $( window ).height() < 660 );
}).triggerHandler( 'resize' );
```

where `container` is a reference to your `#container` element.

`.triggerHandler()` will manually fire the resize event (which in turn will execute the above resize handler), so the above code works both on re-size and on page load.

Comment: also it not necessarily equals the body height but it's most likely what he wants anyway

Comment: @Andy Yes the body / document height is a different value, but I assume that the OP wants the viewport height.

Comment: I love it! This is exactly what I needed, thank you! :D and also thanks to the others who responded on my topic!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(parseInt($('body').height())<660){

}else{

}
```

i thought height() and width() will return integers but yea better parseInt for certainty.

---

if you don't want to use jquery

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].offsetHeight<660){

}else{

}
```

should work.

Comment: He never said that he uses jQuery... I'm not going to -1, just sayin.

Comment: @Cipi - It's in his tags. Andy, you probably want to `parseInt()` on the height, as well. Also, showing the option of `.outerHeight(true)` might be useful.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry... didn't see the jQuery tag.

Comment: np. i'm usually just checking in the jquery tag so i automatically think everyone wants a jquery solution.

Comment: @Andy - That's probably just my paranoia, I always try to ensure the right type is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would point this out for posterity. There may be some cases where you want the entire height of the (`body`) element, not just the `height` property. Use [`.outerHeight(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to get that.

Note, have Firebug/Chrome Console open.

```
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 25px;
}

<p>This is a test</p>

console.log($('body').height());
console.log($('body').outerHeight(true));
```

Which gives you:

```
20
90
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TS2Nn/

To get around this, you could use `html`:

```
console.log('html: '+$('html').height());
console.log('html: '+$('html').outerHeight(true));
console.log('body: '+$('body').height());
console.log('body: '+$('body').outerHeight(true));
```

Which will give you:

```
html: 90
html: 90
body: 20
body: 90
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TS2Nn/2/

Comment: Btw if `$('body')` is replaced with `$('html')`, the logged value will be 90 in both cases. So, if one is interested in the height of the web-page, `$('html').height()` is the most convenient method I believe.

Comment: That's a good point, and I can see why that would work. I left the *(`body`)* in there in case anyone came across it for other reasons (not just `body`), but looking for `html` in this case would be just as profitable as using `.outerHeight(true)`, as far as I can tell.